# Go: using one channels to receive results from multiple goroutines

Tags: go, goroutine

I have a CSV file with thousands of records.
I process each record in a goroutine and I want to gather all the results of processed records in a slice to write them down in another file.
Simplified version of my code is:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    c := make(chan string, 1)
    csvfile, err := os.Open("data.csv")
    reader := csv.NewReader(bufio.NewReader(csvfile))
    //...
    for {
        line, err := reader.Read()
        // ...
        wg.Add(1)
        go processRecord(line, c)
    }
    //...
    results := make([]string, 0)
    for r := range c { // ERROR HERE: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
        results = append(results , r)
    }
    // write results to file
    wg.Wait()
    close(c)
}

func processRecord(data []string, c chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // ...
    c <- *result
}
```

In for loop I get all the results but loop continues after getting last result and I get this error:

```
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

What is wrong with this code? I tried different QAs on SO without any success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for-loop will only terminate once the channel is closed. You are closing the channel after for-loop terminates, hence the deadlock.

You can fix by putting the for-loop into a goroutine:

```
results := make([]string, 0)
done:=make(chan struct{})
go func() {
    for r := range c {
        results = append(results , r)
    }
    close(done)
}()
wg.Wait()
close(c)
<-done
// read results
```

Comment: Doesn't this pattern also need a WaitGroup or channel read to synchronize with results goroutine?

Comment: @DanielFarrell, there is already a waitgroup to wait all goroutines. Why would there be a need to synchronize with the results goroutine?

Comment: otherwise there'd be a race condition  accessing `results` between main and the results func?

Comment: @DanielFarrell, you are correct. Since the original post does not use `result`, there is no race, but assuming `results` will be used after everything is done, additional protection is necessary to protect from a race. I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
for r := range c { // ERROR HERE: fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
    mutex.Lock()
    results = append(results , r)
    mutex.Unlock()
}
```

goroutines are asleep - deadlock! because its written at the same time. Use Mutex can be handle this exception

Comment: No that is not the reason. Mutex will not solve the deadlock problem.